# Annotate text with BIO-scheme using spaCy

Tags: python, annotations, spacy

I need to annotate a text corpus with BIO-scheme based on a rule method (I have a pre-defined list of tokens and their tags). I'm using spaCy's `EntityRuler` class for this task. My question is whether there is a neat and efficient way to implement BIO tagging with spaCy? Also, I'm struggling to implement a multi-token BIO tagging:

```
 'He used sodium-bicarb 5 gr' -> 
['O', 'O', 'B-DRUG', 'I-DRUG', 'I-DRUG', 'B-STRENGTH', 'I-STRENGTH')
```

I have a simple (rule-based) script to tag entities I'm interested in:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load('en')
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp).from_disk('drug_patterns.jsonl')
nlp.add_pipe(ruler, before='ner')


text = 'He has been prescribed ipratropium-albuterol a small dose of 20mg, denzapine and amil-co'
doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

The output:

```
ipratropium 23 34 DRUG
20mg 61 65 STRENGTH
denzapine 67 76 DRUG
amil-co 81 88 DRUG
```

So, I'm not sure how to split `'amil-co'` into three tags `'B-DRUG, I-DRUG and I-DRUG'`.

Ideally, I would like to have the following annotation:

```
    token          BIO
0   He             O
1   has            O
2   been           O
3   prescribed     O
4   ipratropium    B-DRUG
5   -              I-DRUG
6   albuterol      I-DRUG
7   a              O
8   small          O
9   dose           O
10  of             O
11  20             B-STRENGTH
12  mg             I-STRENGTH
13  ,              O
14  denzapine      B-DRUG
15  and            O
16  amil           B-DRUG
17  -              I-DRUG
18  co             I-DRUG
19  .              O
```

**Also**, in my vocabulary `drug_patterns.json`, I may have the same long token appear more then once:

```
{"label": "DRUG", "pattern": [{"lower": "ipratropium"}]}
{"label": "DRUG", "pattern": [{"lower": "ipratropium"}, {"lower": "bromide"}]}
{"label": "DRUG", "pattern": [{"lower": "ipratropium"}, {"lower": "-"}, {"lower": "albuterol"}]}
```

which instead of the entire `ipratropium-albuterol` will pick only the firs (shortest) token `ipratropium` (as displayed in the output). Is there a simple way to tell spaCy to pick the longest token?

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it was an embarrassingly simple solution, but hopefully it might be interesting to others. Simply use `.ent_iob_` and `.ent_type_` attributes of tokens. Namely:

```
pd.DataFrame([(e.text, e.ent_iob_, e.ent_type_) for e in doc])


    0   1   2
0   He  O   
1   has O   
2   been    O   
3   prescribed  O   
4   ipratropium B   DRUG
5   -   O   
6   albuterol   O   
7   a   O   
8   small   O   
9   dose    O   
10  of  O   
11  20  B   STRENGTH
12  mg  I   STRENGTH
13  ,   O   
14  denzapine   B   DRUG
15  and O   
16  amil    B   DRUG
17  -   I   DRUG
18  co  I   DRUG
19  .   O
```

and then one can easily combine the last two columns in an appropriate format with hyphen. SpaCy is great!